# How to not display duplicates from Firebase list observable in Ionic 3 App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ng-options, ngfor

I'm trying to figure how to only display unique categories in an ionic app from a firebase backend. So for every item that a user makes in the app they are given the ability to assign a category to that item. Then when they want to create another item, the previous categories are displayed at the bottom to make it easier for them to add that item to the same category. However, i'm using and ngFor and therefore every item in the firebase list is being displayed, even the duplicates. I believe you can achieve this with ng-option but I've hit a wall.

Here is my addtodo.html.

```
<ion-content padding>

 <ion-item style="margin-top:-10px">
   <ion-label floating>Title</ion-label>
   <ion-input [(ngModel)]="todo.Title"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <ion-item>
   <ion-label floating>Description</ion-label>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="todo.Desc"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label floating>New Category</ion-label>
  <ion-input autocomplete="true" spellcheck="true"  [(ngModel)]="todo.Cat">
</ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Due Date: MM/DD/YYYY</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" pickerFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" 
type="date" min="2017-09-28" max="2017-31-12" [(ngModel)]="todo.Date"></ion-
 datetime>
 </ion-item>

 <button ion-button block style="margin-top:30px" (click)="createToDo()">Add 
 Task</button>

<p style="text-align:center;"><strong >Categories:</strong></p>
<p *ngIf="(todoDataRef$ | async)?.length==0" style="color:gray; text-
align:center;" text-wrap no-lines>Add a new category above and it will be 
saved here for next time!</p>
<ion-buttons *ngFor="let item of todoDataRef$ | async" ng-options="todo.Cat 
for item in todoDataRef$ | unique:'Cat'" no-lines>
    <button ion-button outline style="float:left;" (click)="selectCat()">
{{item.Cat}}</button>
</ion-buttons>
```

here is addtodo.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { Todo } from '../../models/todo';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase,  FirebaseListObservable } from 
'angularfire2/database';

  @IonicPage()
  @Component({
   selector: 'page-addtodo',
   templateUrl: 'addtodo.html',
   })
  export class AddtodoPage {

   todoDataRef$: FirebaseListObservable<Todo[]>;
   todo = {} as Todo;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: 
 AngularFireDatabase, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
 NavParams) {

  this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
  this.todoDataRef$ = this.afDatabase.list(`todo/${auth.uid}`);
  })

 }

 createToDo() {
   this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(auth => {
     this.afDatabase.list(`todo/${auth.uid}`).push(this.todo)
     .then(() => this.navCtrl.setRoot(AboutPage));

   })
 }


}
```

Here is an image of the addtodo page. As you can see there are duplicated categories.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share your observable function

Comment: ok i'm adding it now